# TensorBoard shows loss of validation, but not traininig

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, loss

Something weird happens when I want to show the loss at TensorBoard. Usually, when I use values of epochs below 1k-2k everything is fine, but other times, TensorBoard shows all the validation epochs, but stops showing the training MANY epochs before. Also, TensorBoard doesn't show the exact curve (shape or values) of loss EVEN WITHOUT "Smoothing".
**Someone knows why? or how to fix it?**

*Example:*

**TensorBoard of the same model trained with 5k epochs:**

Training loss values:
[image]

Validation loss values:
[image]

**Matplot of the same information:**
[image]

(A big range of NN with neurons between 5-200 and number of hidden layers between 1-3 have been tested.)